# Could we create a tag to encompass phones and other electronic devices?

Tags: discussion, tags

Could we create a tag to encompass phones and other electronic devices, including laptops and tablets?

Here are some questions that would fit well with such a tag: 
[How to deal with uninterested students during an optional exercise session?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/84388/32436)
https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=phone

Right now, "etiquette" is often used for these types of questions.  "Etiquette" could still be used for some of them, but "etiquette" doesn't only refer to cell phone etiquette.

Answer (score 3):

We have a [technology](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) tag already. See e.g. [Incorporating Cellphone use in a Course](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/67871/incorporating-cellphone-use-in-a-course)

However, it should not be applied to [How to deal with uninterested students?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/84388/32436).
Phones or laptops are not integral to the question of dealing with uninterested students - the question would be the same if the student was reading a book, working on homework for another course, or doing the New York Times crossword puzzle in class. Nor should it be applied to *all* questions that happen to include the word "phone". Tags should reflect what a question is fundamentally about.

Comment: In theory, your idea seems like it might work, with a tag synonym in place; but in practice, it doesn't seem to be working.  I just reviewed a bunch of questions that talk about cell phones that don't have the *technology* tag.  I think the term "electronic device" is used more often than "technology."

Comment: @aparente001: Then, let’s create a synonym.

Comment: I [changed the tag wiki accordingly](http://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/20865/revisions).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft - I like your edit.  But could you also either give examples (cell phones, laptops, tablets, electronic devices), or else put those in a synonym?

Comment: @aparente001: *But could you also either give examples […]?* – It’s in the tag wiki. I think it would be too much for the excerpt. — *I couldn't do it.* – Everybody can suggest tag-wiki edits. Almost nobody can suggest synonyms (including me for this tag), because the synonym system sucks. — *or else put those in a synonym?* – Why not make all those terms synonyms?